# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinputplus' in VScode

Tags: python-3.x

**I am using Windows 10 64bit
I also pip installed pyinputplus in command prompt
I am in 3.7.9 virtual environment in VSCode**

code:
import pyinputplus as pyip

response = ('Enter a number: ')

Error message:
import pyinputplus as pyip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinputplus'

any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried running the code in command prompt? I have a similar problem with PyCharm on my Mac. I pip install, but my PyCharm interpreter doesn't recognize them. However, when I run those codes in terminal it runs.

Comment: After doing `import sys`, show us what `sys.version` and `sys.path` look like. A convenient way to inspect the path is with `$ python -m site`

Comment: NICE!! once i reached the correct file path, i installed 'pyinputplus', entered 'python' into command line and was able to successfully run program from there.  Many thanks

Comment: do i need to run a virtual env before running import sys?  i can't even find python 3.10 path in my desktop, C: drive, etc.